# I have to give some dependent fields in html,php,javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to give some dependency in the fields. Ex:
first i have two option that is **Branch/Staff** so, if i am selecting **branch** it should display the **branches to select** if he is selecting **staff** then i should be able to select the **employee id** and if am selecting employee id **employee name** should display and more over all these things user needs to feed the data. That is main category branch/staff should be standard but there after branches,employee number and name al these things user needs to feed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function updatePrice() {
      // Get the ex-GST price from its form element
var exPrice = document.getElementById("product_price").value;
var gstPrice = document.getElementById("cgst").value;

// Get the GST price
gstPrice = exPrice * 0.09;
var TPrice = parseInt(gstPrice) + parseInt(exPrice) + parseInt(gstPrice);

// Set the GST price in its form element
document.getElementById("cgst").value = gstPrice;
document.getElementById("igst").value = gstPrice;
document.getElementById("sgst").value = 0;
document.getElementById("total").value = TPrice;

}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<?php
public function addProduct($pro_name,$price,$stock,$date,$loc,$in_no,$gst_no,$cgst,$sgst,$igst,$total,$depre,$pur_from){
        $pre_stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `products`( `product_name`, `product_price`, `product_stock`, `added_date`, `p_status`, `loc`, `in_no`, `gst_no`, `cgst`, `sgst`, `igst`, `total`, `depre`, `pur_from`) 
             VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

            $status = 1;            

        $pre_stmt->bind_param("sdisisiiddddis",$cid,$bid,$pro_name,$price,$stock,$date,$status,$loc,$in_no,$gst_no,$cgst,$sgst,$igst,$total,$depre,$pur_from);
        $result = $pre_stmt->execute() or die($this->con->error);
        if ($result) {
            return "NEW_PRODUCT_ADDED";
        }else{
            return 0;
        }

    }
  if (isset($_POST["added_date"]) AND isset($_POST["product_name"]) ) {
    $obj = new DBOperation();
    $result = $obj->addProduct($_POST["select_cat"],
                            $_POST["select_brand"],
                            $_POST["product_name"],
                            $_POST["product_price"],
                            $_POST["product_qty"],
                            $_POST["added_date"],
                            $_POST["loc"],
                            $_POST["in_no"],
                            $_POST["gst_no"],
                            $_POST["cgst"],
                            $_POST["sgst"], 
                            $_POST["igst"],
                            $_POST["total"],
                            $_POST["depre"],                
                            $_POST["pur_from"]);
    echo $result;
    exit();
}
?>
<div class="modal fade" id="form_products" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add new products</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="product_form" onsubmit="return false">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Category</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="select_cat" name="select_cat" required/>



            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Brand</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="select_brand" name="select_brand" required/>



            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">

                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label>RHFL ID</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_name" id="product_name" placeholder="Enter RHFL ID" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label>Invoice No</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="in_no" id="in_no" placeholder="Enter Invoice No" required>
            </div> 
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">

            <label>Location</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="loc" name="loc" placeholder="Enter Location" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>Purchase Date</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="added_date" name="added_date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" readonly/>
                    </div>

          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>Product Price</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product_price" name="product_price" onChange="updatePrice()" />
          </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label>GST No</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="gst_no" name="gst_no" placeholder="Enter GST No" required/>
            </div>


          </div>


          <div class="form-row">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>Purchased From</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pur_from" name="pur_from" placeholder="Enter From Where you purchased" required/>
          </div> 
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>IGST</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="igst" name="igst" onChange="updatePrice()" />
          </div>

           </div> 
           <div class="form-row">
           <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="cgst">CGST</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cgst" name="cgst" readonly name="cgst" onChange="updatePrice()" />
          </div>






          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>SGST</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sgst" name="sgst" onChange="updatePrice()" />
          </div>
          </div>
           <div class="form-row">

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>Quantity</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product_qty" name="product_qty" placeholder="Enter Quantity" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>Depreciation</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="depre" name="depre" placeholder="Enter Price of SGST" required/>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">

            <label>Total</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total" name="total" onChange="updatePrice(this.form)" />

          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add Product</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
//add product
    $("#product_form").on("submit",function(){
        $.ajax({
                url : DOMAIN+"/includes/process.php",
                method : "POST",
                data : $("#product_form").serialize(),
                success : function(data){
                    if (data == "NEW_PRODUCT_ADDED") {
                        alert("New Product Added Successfully..!");
                        $("#product_name").val("");
                        $("#select_cat").val("");
                        $("#select_brand").val("");
                        $("#product_price").val("");
                        $("#product_qty").val("");
                        calculate();
                    }else{
                        console.log(data);
                        alert(data);
                    }

                }
            })
    })
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: I want to add some responsive dependent fields

Comment: Well, I would use AJAX and send the selected option, to a PHP script on the back end that returns the select box and options that I want.  But it's too much for me to explain how to do.

Comment: If you any sample please give me the code or if you have time please help me out

Comment: This page explains the process quite well: https://snippets.webaware.com.au/snippets/populate-form-from-database-using-ajax-and-json/

Comment: No it is not working